# background image in Bootstrap theme templates does not seem to show in styles or divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a strange situation here. I've tried both adding a bg image to a customized style to override/extend a bootstrap style (column) as well as just embed a style in the div attribute.  For whatever reason, neither seems to work.
examples..

```
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center" style="background:image 
   url('images/test_back.jpg')">
        <img class="rounded-circle" alt="140x140" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;" 
     src="images/140X140.gif" data-holder-rendered="true">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      </div>
```

Then, in another one I do the following:

in the HTML file:

```
   <div class="columns divboxshadow_rt"> 
   <p class="thumbnail_align"> <img src="images/bkg_06.jpg" alt="" class="thumbnail"/> </p>
   <h4>Bargains ()</h4>
   <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
   <img src="images/deals-steals1.png"  class="d-block w-80" alt="Steals and Deals 10">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The above does not work...HTML that does have a style reference embedded in the div tag that does work...

```
    <div class="columns" style="background-image: 
    url('images/test_back.jpg')">
```

in the CSS file:

```
    .divboxshadow_rt {
    width: 22%;
    background-image: url('images/test_back.jpg');
    /*  border-left: none; thin #BFB9B9;*/  
    border: 2px solid #968E8E;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: hidden;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding: 2px ;
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin: 5px auto;

    box-shadow:0 4px 5px #888888;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 11px ;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px ;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align:center;
   }
```

BTW, neither that bkg image ref housed in the divboxshadow_rt class embedded in single or double quotes works.
Any ideas what could be preventing this from being rendered? This seems like it should be pretty straightforward. I should clarify that all of the attributes in the divshadowbox class above are showing, EXCEPT for the bg image. I have since altered this CSS file and this class, but I have another issue in that the left border seems to show no matter what I do - i.e. make it hidden, none, etc. I looked at the BS CSS file and I don't see cols listed with border attributes so I wouldn't think that affects it. Anyone know why a border on the left side would show no matter what? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I solved the box shadow issue with the border. Still looking for suggestions on the background image if anyone would know why it won't paint to the DIV tag.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is strange. This was a false read from the IDE of the Creative Cloud in DreamWeaver! Very aggravating, and not sure why it works this way, but it would not traverse to the path properly where my basic HTML or template file was saved.
So DW wanted to go to /images/img.jpg or "images/img.jpg but needed to traverse up one more directory to get there! Problem solved, finally.

Answer (score 0):

wow. It turns out the IDE in Dreamweaver was incorrectly mapping these for some reason. Luckily I figured it out and fixed it; problem solved.